# Kubernetes: view logs of crashed Airflow worker pod

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

Pods on our k8s cluster are scheduled with `Airflow`'s `KubernetesExecutor`, which runs all `Task`s in a new pod.

I have a such a `Task` for which the pod instantly (after 1 or 2 seconds) crashes, and for which of course I want to see the logs.

This seems hard. As soon the pod crashes, it gets deleted, along with the ability to retrieve crash logs. I already tried all of:

- `kubectl logs -f <pod> -p`: cannot be used since these pods are named uniquely
  (courtesy of `KubernetesExecutor`).
- `kubectl logs -l label_name=label_value`: I
  struggle to apply the labels to the pod (if this is a known/used way of working, I'm happy to try further)
- An shared `nfs` is mounted on all pods on a fixed log directory. The failing pod however, does not log to this folder.
- When I am really quick I run `kubectl logs -f -l dag_id=sample_dag --all-containers (`dag_id`label is added by`Airflow`)`
   between running and crashing and see `Error from server (BadRequest): container "base" in pod "my_pod" is waiting to start: ContainerCreating`. This might give me some clue but:

  - these are only but the last log lines
  - this is really backwards

I'm basically looking for the canonical way of retrieving logs from transient pods

Comment: I am also seeing the same issue, I added s3 connection but its not able to send logs to S3, and I dont see any error message also, Can you please let me know how you fixed this issue?

Comment: doing as accepted answer worked for me... Also, UI's such as Octant/Dashboard gave me additional clues which I missed with plain `kubectl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable remote logging. Code sample below is for using S3. In `airflow.cfg` set the following:

```
remote_logging = True
remote_log_conn_id = my_s3_conn
remote_base_log_folder = s3://airflow/logs
```

The `my_s3_conn` can be set in airflow>Admin>Connections. In the `Conn Type` dropdown, select `S3`.